# Create csv file with more than one column

Tags: powershell

I have multiple PSCustomObjects and I want to store these values in a csv file.

My code stores the values in the csv file but I always get a csv file with one column.

Here is my code to create the csv file:

```
function Create-CSVFile
{
    <#
    Create a CSV file with the information of the xml files
    #>
    [CmdletBinding ()]
    Param
    (
         [Parameter(
            Mandatory,
            Position=0)] 
         [PSCustomObject] $values
    )
    $csvFile = Join-Path -Path $PSScriptRoot -ChildPath "xmlInformation.csv"
    $values | Export-Csv $csvFile -NoTypeInformation
 }
```

Here is the definition of my PSCustomObject:

```
[PSCustomObject]@{
  'ID' = $metadata.id
  'Owners' = $metadata.owners
}
```

Here is a sample of my PSCustomObject:

```
ID                              Owners                          
--                              ------                          
32472304239472304               Klaus,Hans
35057435349563444               Michael
54353453453453455               Olaf
12354534534534553               Anna,Thomas
```

Here is a result of the csv file:

```
"ID","Owners"
"32472304239472304","Klaus,Hans"
"35057435349563444","Michael"
"54353453453453455","Olaf"
"12354534534534553","Anna,Thomas"
```

The rows in the csv file looks fine but everything is placed in the first column.

Comment: Show a sample of the PSCustomObjects you have, and of the resulting CSV file.

Comment: The CSV file indeed looks fine.  Try "Import-Csv myfile.csv | format-table".  As long as your culture uses comma as the separator,  you should see a well formed table with two columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then you are looking at the results by double-clicking the csv file, so it opens in Excel.

Your system's locale - and therefore Excel - may use a different delimiter character than the standard comma.

To produce a csv file that has the same delimiter character your Excel uses, add switch `-UseCulture`:

```
Export-Csv $csvFile -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function looks fine, the error might be the way you are calling the function?

Here how I tried it:

```
$myObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
    a = 22
    b = 33
}

Create-CSVFile $myObject
```

**Result:**

```
"a","b"
"22","33"
```